# Image from clicked item of Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to Android app development. I am trying to display the image and text in another `Activity` from the item of the `Recyclerview` which was clicked by the user. I am getting unreachable statement error. Please help me out!

Here's my code for getting image:

```
imgUrl = new getDataAsyncTask().getImageUrl(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
```

and the full `Activity` code:

```
public class RestaurantsAndCafesActivity extends Activity {

public static final String URL = "http://192.168.8.101:80/jay.html";

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RCRecyclerAdapter adapter;
public String imgUrl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reyclerview_layout);

    /* Initialize RecyclerView */
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //parseResult();

    new getDataAsyncTask().execute();

    final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(RestaurantsAndCafesActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

    });


    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());
            if(child!=null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)){
                Toast.makeText(RestaurantsAndCafesActivity.this,"Clicked Number "+recyclerView.getChildPosition(child), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
                imgUrl = new getDataAsyncTask().getImageUrl(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }
    });
}
public class getDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
     ArrayList<FeedItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getImageUrl(int pos) 
    {
        return arrayList.get(pos).thumb;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
                org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
                for(Element e : document.select("img[src]"))
                {
                    Elements imgScr = e.select("img[src]");
                    String elements = imgScr.attr("src");
                    String text = imgScr.attr("alt");
                    String desc = imgScr.attr("title");

                    arrayList.add(new FeedItem(text, elements, desc));
                }
            }
        catch(IOException e)
            {

            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(RestaurantsAndCafesActivity.this,"Loading","Please Wait",true,false);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        adapter = new RCRecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

}
```

I just want to get the image url so that I can send it to another `Activity` via `Intent.putExtra` method. Please tell me where I am going wrong, or is there any other way for what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onInterceptTouchEvent` the

`imgUrl = new getDataAsyncTask().getImageUrl(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));` needs to be before `return true`. It's declared after `return true;` which makes the statement unreachable.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek Dabholkar, that statement unreachable error is gone now. But there's one new problem now, as I said before that I wanted to display the image on ImageView of another Acitvity from the RecyclerView item which was clicked by the user. I wanted to extract the imageurl from the arrayList and use it to display the image on ImageView of the other Acitvity, But the app crashes giving me this error in the logcat: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`

Comment: The RecyclerView displays the data but when I click on it to open another activity, it says IndexOutOfBound.

Comment: Try with `getLayoutPosition` instead of `getChildPosition`